# Convertir consulta SQL a Eloquent Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Tengo esta Consulta en sql, este codigo como yo quiero ya que trae el conteo de la cantidad que deseo.

```
SELECT c.id, c.name ,COUNT(p.id) as num FROM categories c LEFT JOIN products p ON c.id = p.product_type GROUP BY c.id
```

y el resultado es:

```
   id   name    num 
    1   General  1  
    2   ASEO    1   
    3   COMIDA  0
```

¿Como traer el mismo resultado consultado con el Eloquent de laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Si te interesa algo con eloquent y no el query builder, debes de crear una relación en tus modelos, en tu modelo de products, crea una relación a product_types, y categories (esto suponiendo que entiendo bien el query)

```php
// En tu modelo de Products, crea la relación con ProductTypes y Category
public function product_type()
{
    return $this->hasOne(ProductType::class);
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::class);
}
```

Al especificar la relación, después puedes crear un query con eager loading, para cargar la información de category y product type de un producto.

```
Product::with('category', 'product_type')->get();
```

Comment: Estoy suponiendo que un producto tiene solamente un tipo de producto y una categoría, no hay más información al respecto. Si un producto pudiera tener más tipos y categorías, se podría cambiar la relación.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto puede servirte:

```
$r = DB::table('categories as c')
    ->select('c.id', 'c.name', DB::raw('COUNT(p.id) as num'))
    ->leftJoin('products as p', 'c.id', 'p.product_type')
    ->groupBy('c.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Es correcto, voy a probar

Comment: Asi es Eduardo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, eso era.

Answer (score 0):

Asi como dices, segun los select que haga, tengo que agruparlos. Muchas gracias.

```
$r = DB::table('categories as c')
                    ->select('c.id', 'c.name', DB::raw('COUNT(p.id) as products_count'))
                    ->leftJoin('products as p', 'c.id', 'p.product_type')
                    ->groupBy('c.id')
                    ->groupBy('c.name')
                    ->get();
```